# Error while building Unity project for Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

Just tried to build Unity project as a test for Android.

I got this error:

```
Error building Player: Win32Exception: 
ApplicationName='C:/Users/My User/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe', 
CommandLine='devices', 
CurrentDirectory='C:/Users/My User/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk
```

What have I done wrong?

Note: I'm new to Android development and used a tutorial to install the JDK and Android Studio. Wouldn't be surprised if I messed up somewhere lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive about what's wrong.

I recommend the following:

1. Ensure that Edit > Preferences > External Tools > Android SDK path
   is correct.
2. Make sure you have the necessary packages.
3. Check/Ensure your SDK permissions are correct.
4. Re-installation of the SDK.

Here is some information i came upon in the Unity Forums as well:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/861959/build-and-run-to-android-problems.html

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll uninstall and start over. Just one more thing, what do you mean by SDK permission? Is that something you do at installation or afterwards?

Comment: Generally you want to make sure your user account has rights to use the SDK packages. If you're running as admin, then you're probably fine to be honest. If your path is correct, then adb.exe is probably not being found on execution. One suggestion i found elsewhere states that they copied the adb.exe and it's .dll's to the tools folder. Not sure if that is logically the bext fix, but it may be a work-around.